# Assiging a new variable to each iteration of a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im trying to create a for each loop that will provide a different variable for each iteration of the array.

As it stands my loop will run and my variable $new will be the final value only, 17. Is there a way to get a different variable assigned to each iteration?

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17);    

foreach($a as $value) {
  echo $new = $value;
}

echo $new; 

?>
```

Comment: on what reason why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a dynamic array.

Comment: you already did that when you made the initial array

Comment: when you say provide, do you mean display? you should put `echo $value` inside your foreach loop.

Comment: A dynamic array was what i was using now but what if i want 1, 2, 3, 17 all to be in different variables so that that i can call them later on. I dont want to echo them. If i have further functions and i want to call them, how do i do this best?

Comment: why can't you call them now with $a[0], $a[1] etc? or $alpha=$a[0],$beta=$a[1] etc

Comment: That's not a dynamic array, that is static. I assumed `$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17);` was not literal, just a reference. `$a[0]` and `$new` should function the same.

Comment: I think you might be looking for the [list function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). You can do something like `$a = array(1, 2, 3, 17);list($new1,$new2,$new3,$new4) = $a`. Then, `$new1` will be 1, `$new2` will be 2, `$new3` will be 3, and `$new4` will be 17.

Answer (score 0):

forget the foreach loop and simply pick a random value from the array Answer provided from "http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php":

```
$new= $a[mt_rand(0, count($a) - 1)];
echo $new;
```

or

```
$new=array_random($a)
echo $new;
```